# Access a fragment variable from recycler view adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-recyclerview

Is there a way we can access and assign values for variables in fragments from an adapter without using a listener or public method in fragment?

```
((Activity) context).variable = someValue;
```

We can use above method to access activity variables from an adapter. But it doesn't work like that way for fragments. Any method like above that work for fragments?

Comment: Take a look at this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372218/access-fragment-from-adapter

Comment: More like `((MyActivity) getActivity()).setVariable(value);`, but it's not recommended.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier so what is the recommended method?

Comment: Yes, or you can use a `Singleton`, or use a pattern `MVP` to structure your code.

Comment: @PedroCardoso That was not I was looking for!!! Thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do that like, when you create your adapter, pass the fragment as a param.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MyFragment fragmentA,...);
```

Then inside your adapter, you could use that fragmentA instance by simply referring to it.

If you do not want to pass directly your Fragment object type into your adapter, you could:

- Define an interface.
- Implement interface in your fragment.
 
- Pass the interface instance when you create your adapter.